# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed

Tags: asp.net, mysql, frameworks, entity, connector

I developing a `asp.net` website with `entity` framework.

- **Setup of my local PC:**

  - Windows 8
  - Visual Studio 2012 Update 3
  - Install Mysql connector (library version 6.7.4)
  - connect to database server MySQL using EntityFramework
- **And I have another windows 2008 web edition server with the following setup:**

  - .Net framework 4.5
  - MySQL connector
  - MySQL Server 5.6

The problem is that after I finish coding on my local PC, i publish it to my server and it show the following message when i try to run it, but in my local PC it works fine:

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed

First I wondered it is because it cannot connect to MySQL server but when I test coding with classic ADO.NET to MySQL, it works fine in my Windows server. So i suspect it is because entity library problem but i don't know what exactly it is.

Does anybody know what is causing this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code you already have?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try adding the following to your App/Web config:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories >
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Comment: Saved my butt with this :) Thanks :) I had version 6.8.3.0 so I just had to modify the version number but it worked great :)